# Retrieve the first/last line of subshell stdout

Tags: bash, shell, subshell

If I have a subshell command:

```
output="$(runfoo)";
```

is there way to store only the last line of the output from `runfoo` into the variable `output`? Or perhaps only the first line?

Comment: Simple first line (without extra child processes) would be `read -r output < <(runfoo)`  - not so simple to use `read` to get the last line though.

Comment: I think we have an answer from Cyrus

Comment: I know, I see it as a challenge to get an answer without using external programs.

Comment: humma you consider head/tail external programs?

Comment: There *are* external programs, they are not part of any shell.  Do a `type echo` (shell builtin, part of the shell) then a `type head` or `type tail`.

Comment: Well I guess, but they are more built-in than some user-land bash function

Comment: Really?  What leads you to that conclusion?   There are a lot of builtins, but common commands, like `cat`, `ls`, `grep`, `cut`, `basename`, are external programs that carry an overhead and are often used unnecessarily.  I'm not saying never use those programs, simplicity is often a good justification - the answer by @Cyrus is an example - but it is a test of skill to avoid them.

Comment: See also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Hmmm, I would guess that those programs you just named are POSIX standards or whatever, like standardized stuff that's proven to work etc

Comment: @cdarke if you want to add an answer w/o using the tail/head commands, I will upvote, please consider upvoting the question as well lulz

Comment: By your comments I think you misunderstand what I was trying to do.  The phrase "built-in" has a specific meaning with a shell.  It means that the command is part of the shell binary and runs in the same process.   You use the term *command* for `head(1)` and `tail(1)`.  That's correct, but remember that these are *programs* whereas `echo`, `read` and `cd` (for example) are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only stdout:

```
output="$(runfoo | tail -n 1)"

output="$(runfoo | head -n 1)"
```

Stdout and stderr:

```
output="$(runfoo 2>&1 | tail -n 1)"

output="$(runfoo 2>&1 | head -n 1)"
```

Comment: LGTM mucho liko for this one...no love for the question tho

Answer (score 0):

With bash

```
IFS=$'\n' output=$(inter=($(runfoo))
printf '%s\n' "${inter[0]}" "${inter[((${#inter[@]}-1))]}")
echo "$output"
```

runfoo return a multiline result like that :

first aaa

xcv

pattern3 a

bbb

last qqq

inter is a array (inter for intermediary)

inter=($(runfoo)) get the result of the runfoo command '$(runfoo)'
in the array inter=($(...))

This way,

inter[0]=first

inter[1]=aaa

inter[6]=bbb

because IFS= whitespace tab or newline

So setting IFS to newline at the start

Each item of the array inter is a line of text

inter[0]=first aaa

inter[2]=pattern 3

output=$(create a array and print the first and the last item of this array)

So echo "$output"

first aaa

last qqq

Hope this help.

Comment: can you explain in English what your command is doing? not sure sure what the `inter` command is, never heard of it

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman updated the answer with try of explain in English